# Kommas in »Ein Interview ist, im Vergleich zu einem Hearing, entspannter.«

Tags: grammar-identification, comma

Meine Frau hat mich soeben um Hilfe bei einem deutschen Satz gebeten, aber ich konnte ihr keine klare Antwort geben. Ihre ursprüngliche Frage war:

*Ist das Komma in diesem Satz korrekt?*

> 1. Ein Interview ist entspannter, im Vergleich zu einem Hearing.

Ich konnte das nicht beantworten, weil mir nicht klar ist, welche Art von Satzglied der Teil *»im Vergleich zu einem Hearing«* ist. Mir ist schon mal nicht ganz klar, ob das eine Ergänzung des Verbs *»ist«* ist, oder eine Ergänzung des Adjektivs *»entspannter«,* und mir ist auch nicht klar, welche Art von Ergänzung das ist. Und daher ist mir auch nicht ganz klar, ob hier ein Komma zwingend erforderlich, verboten, oder optional ist.

Ich habe meiner Frau geraten, das fragliche Satzglied zwischen Verb und Adjektiv zu stellen, weil ich fand, dass der Satz dann flüssiger klingt, und meine Frau hat mir sofort zugestimmt:

> 2. Ein Interview ist, im Vergleich zu einem Hearing, entspannter.

Eine dritte Möglichkeit wäre dieser Satz:

> 3. Im Vergleich zu einem Hearing, ist ein Interview entspannter.

Aber die Frage, ob dieses Satzglied vom Hauptsatz durch Kommas abzutrennen ist, bleibt eigentlich dieselbe. Allerdings tendierte ich in der ersten Version des Satzes eher dazu, ein Komma einzufügen, während ich in der zweiten Version eher kein Komma machen würde. In der dritten Version bin ich mir eigentlich sogar sicher, dass hier kein Komma hingehört. Aber ich kann das nicht begründen.

**Meine Fragen:**
1. Wie ist die korrekte Bezeichnung für das fragliche Satzglied?
2. Sind die Kommas in den drei Versionen des Satzes zwingend erforderlich, verboten, oder optional? Und warum ist das so?

Comment: Wieso hat diese Frage vier Antworten, aber nicht eine einzige Auf- oder Abwertung, zumindest von einem der Antwortenden? (Die derzeit einzige Aufwertung ist meine.)

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich: Das habe ich mich auch gefragt, aber ich will nicht jammern. Immerhin habe ich ohnehin um ca. 20.000 Punkte mehr als der User mit den zweitmeisten Punkten. https://german.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=all

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Zu diesem Ungleichgewicht will ich eigentlich *keinen* Beitrag leisten, aber bei dieser Art von Komma-Konstruktion wird mir auch immer ganz ungemütlich.

Comment: @Wolf: Dieses "Ungleichgewicht" ist hauptsächlich dadurch entstanden, dass ich bisher 1448 Fragen beantwortet habe, während es nur einen einzigen andern User gibt, der ebenfalls mehr als 1000 Fragen beantwortet hat (Janka mit 1013 Antworten), und dass 157 meiner Antworten 10 oder mehr Punkte bekommen haben und 19 sogar 25 oder mehr Punkte. Das Ungleichgewicht ist also keineswegs eine Ungerechtigkeit. Das schon seinen guten Grund.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

## Wie ist die korrekte Bezeichnung für das fragliche Satzglied?

Es handelt sich um eine Adverbiale der Art und Weise, die vom Wort «entspannter» abhängt.

### Bezugwort der Präpositionalgruppe

Dass die Präpositionalgruppe vom Wort «entspannter» abhängt, lässt sich durch die Vorfeldprobe ermitteln. Sie kann nämlich zusammen mit dem Adjektiv ins Vorfeld verschoben werden:

1. Entspannter im Vergleich zu einem Hearing ist ein Interview.

Oder auch:

2. Im Vergleich zu einem Hearing entspannter ist ein Interview.

Denselben Befund gibt die Frageprobe:

3. Wie ist das Interview? – Entspannter im Vergleich zu einem Hearing.
4. Auf welche Art und Weise (ist ein Interview) entspannter? – Im Vergleich zu einem Hearing.

Im Gegensatz dazu erscheint mir der folgende Satz eher unwahrscheinlich, der auf eine Abhängigkeit vom Wort «ein Interview» hindeuten würde:

5. Ein Interview im Vergleich zu einem Hearing ist entspannter.

Dieser Satz ist zwar ebenso möglich wie die Umformungen 1. und 2., aber er hat eine andere Bedeutung als der Ausgangssatz. Dies wird besonders deutlich, wenn man die attributive Präpositionalgruppe zu einem Relativsatz umformt:

6. Ein Interview, das im Vergleich zu einem Hearing ist, ist entspannter.

Die Bedeutung dieses Satzes ist dieselbe wie in 5., aber eine leicht andere als im Ausgangssatz, denn hier geht es um die Art des Interviews, im Ausgangssatz hingegen um die Art und Weise seines Entspannter-Seins.

### Abhängiges Satzglied oder nicht?

Wie du bereits angemerkt hast, lässt die Präpositionalgruppe selber ins Vorfeld sich verschieben. Dies würde eigentlich darauf hinweisen, dass sie ein eigenständiges Satzglied wäre:

7. Im Vergleich zu einem Hearing ist ein Interview entspannter.

In der Dudengrammatik heisst es dazu (6., neu bearb. Aufl. 1998, S. 645):

> Wortgruppen, die von prädikativen Satzadjektiven abhängen, haben oft die Tendenz, den Status eigenständiger, das heisst frei verschiebbarer Satzglieder anzunehmen.

Dazu hat es die folgenden Beispiele:

8. Er ist stolz auf seine Tochter.
9. Auf seine Tochter ist er stolz.

Der Grund für dieses relativ freie Auftreten dürfte wohl darin liegen, dass das Verb «sein» zusammen mit dem prädikativen Satzadjektiv einen beinahe verbalen Verbund bildet. Es ist also fast so, als ob *entspannter-sein* (oder *stolz-sein)* ein einziges Verb bildete.

## Sind die Kommas in den drei Versionen des Satzes zwingend erforderlich, verboten, oder optional? Und warum ist das so?

Die Kommas oder die Gedankenstriche, die an ihrer Stelle verwendet werden können, sind optional. Dies entspricht [Regel §78](https://grammis.ids-mannheim.de/rechtschreibung/6201#par78) des amtlichen Regelwerks, wonach es oft im Ermessen der Schreibenden liegt, ob sie «etwas mit Komma als Zusatz oder Nachtrag kennzeichnen» wollen oder nicht.

Dabei ist anzumerken, dass die Kennzeichnung «als Zusatz oder Nachtrag» nicht bedeutet, dass die Präpositionalgruppe nicht mehr ein Satzglied wäre, sondern lediglich, dass ihre Verbindung zum Rest des Satzes etwas lockerer wird, was sich etwa bezeichnen lässt durch eine kurze Sprechpause, einen gesonderten Intonationsverlauf oder die Stellung im Nachfeld des Satzes.

Also wäre ein Komma besonders dann angezeigt, wenn die Präpositionalgruppe – wie im Ausgangssatz – im Nachfeld steht:

10. Ein Interview ist entspannter, im Vergleich zu einem Hearing.

Wenn die Präpositionalgruppe hingegen im Vorfeld steht, dann ist sie besonders stark ins Satzgefüge integriert, denn zwischen Vorfeld und Verb wäre eine Sprechpause oder ein gesonderter Intonationsverlauf unangebracht. Also sollte man hier kein Komma setzen:

11. Im Vergleich zu einem Hearing ist ein Interview entspannter.

Im Mittelfeld sind beide Optionen möglich:

12. Ein Interview ist im Vergleich zu einem Hearing entspannter.
13. Ein Interview ist, im Vergleich zu einem Hearing, entspannter.

Comment: Na, das nenne ich mal eine fundierte Antwort! Vielen Dank!

Answer (score 4):

Ich halte schon den Ausgangssatz für grammatikalisch nicht ganz sauber und führe die Analyse-Probleme darauf zurück.

Wir haben einen Komparativ, also wird etwas verglichen, in der einfachsten Form lautet der Satz also:

> Ein Interview ist entspannter als ein Hearing.

[Rechtschreibregelwerk](https://grammis.ids-mannheim.de/rechtschreibung/6201#), §74, E3 sagt aus, dass hier das Komma falsch wäre.

Jetzt wird - m. E. eher umgangssprachlich - *als + Nominativ* durch die *im Vergleich mit + Dativ* ersetzt. Das ändert nichts daran, dass es sich um einen einfachen Hauptsatz handelt.
Ich sehe nur das Gegenargument, dass es sich um einen Zusatz oder Nachsatz nach § 77 handelt; m. E. ist das nicht stichhaltig, weil *x ist ~Komparativ~* nicht vollständig ist. Damit bleibt das Komma in Beispiel 1 und 3 falsch.

Nur §78 kann die mittlere Konstruktion retten:

> Oft liegt es im Ermessen des Schreibenden, ob er etwas mit Komma als Zusatz oder Nachtrag kennzeichnen will oder nicht.

Answer (score 2):

Das Problem ist "nur", dass die Kommas bei der flüssigen Variante eigentlich Gedankenstriche wären:

> Ein Interview ist – im Vergleich zu einem Hearing – entspannter.

Aber zum Lesen nimmt man gerne Kommas:

> Du hast, so gesehen, Recht.

Wahrscheinlich in Analogie zu:

> Du hast, wenn man es so sieht, Recht.

Falsch scheint mir

> ? So gesehen, hast du Recht.
>   So gesehen ... hast du Recht.
>   So gesehen: Du hast Recht.

Aber

> Du hast Recht, so gesehen.
>   Du hast Recht. So gesehen.

geht, weil man paraktisch alles so hinten anfügen kann.

---

> Er ist sozusagen gesund (praktisch wieder gesund)
>   Er ist, so zu sagen, gesund (?)
>   Er ist, sozusagen, gesund (aber nicht wirklich)

Comment: Vielen Dank für deine persönlichen Meinungen zu ähnlichen Problemstellungen, aber du hast leider keine einzige meiner Fragen beantwortet.

Comment: Genaus das ist meine Antwort. Tja - leider.

Comment: StackExchange ist kein Forum dessen Zweck die Meinungsäußerung der Benutzer ist. Es ist eine Frage-Antwort-Plattform. Jemand stellt eine Frage und andere Benutzer beantworten diese Frage. Allfällige Unklarheiten können in Kommentaren verhandelt werden, auch Meinungsäußerungen kann man dort unterbringen. Aber das, was du als "Antwort" bezeichnest, ist vielleicht eine Reaktion auf die Frage, aber eben keine Antwort.